# Excel Calendar - Filling cells with a different color if dates overlap

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have created a calendar within Excel. Based on a list of events, paired with start and end dates, the corresponding cells will populate to show where the project takes place. This is completed with conditional formatting rules. In certain cases, two dates overlap and only one color will display (thus hiding the other date). Please refer to my image:
 [image: ExcelSchedule]

You will notice the month of February has two overlapping projects, but only one will show because they fall on the same days. How can I have Excel automatically show two colors on a cell if there are two events on the same day?

Answer (score 0):

I would conditional highlight all the dates that fall between the start and end date. This can be done pretty easily with the standard conditional formatting options. Then for any overlaps, use a new rule with a formula similar to this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(([calendar cell without $]>=[range of all start dates with $])*([calendar cell without $]<=[range of all end dates with $]))>1`

And format the new rule with whatever format you want to indicate the overlap. Make sure the new rule appears at the top of the list in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `without $`?

Comment: The $ is referring to the difference between absolute and relative references. When entering a formula in conditional formatting, Excel will use absolute references by default (e.g. $A$1). You have to manually delete the '$' to make the references relative, which is required for the answer I gave.